# JOGL - uniform int variable and for loop causes shader linking error

Tags: opengl, shader, jogl, fragment-shader

I've got a shader which blends multiple textures. I send number of textures as uniform int variable. When I iterate over textures (using this variable in for condition), shader linking fails, but when I place exact number of textures, everything works fine

```
 //this works

if(numberOfTextures==2) { //checking if this var really contains 2 - true

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            texturesBlend += texture2D(gSamplers[i], TexCoord0.xy);
    }
    texturesBlend /= numberOfTextures;
}

//this does not work
if(numberOfTextures==2) {

    for(int i=0;i<numberOfTextures;i++) { //variable in condition - this causes linking error
            texturesBlend += texture2D(gSamplers[i], TexCoord0.xy);
    }
    texturesBlend /= numberOfTextures;
}
```

What may be cause of this problem? If I can check what is value of variable, why can't I use it in condition?

EDIT
full shader source

```
#version 150
const int MAX_TEXTURES = 6;

in vec2 TexCoord0;
in vec3 Normal0;

out vec4 FragColor;

struct DirectionalLight
{
    vec3 Color;
    float AmbientIntensity;
    float DiffuseIntensity;
    vec3 Direction;
};

uniform DirectionalLight gDirectionalLight;
uniform int numberOfTextures;
uniform sampler2D gSamplers[MAX_TEXTURES];

void main()
{
    vec4 AmbientColor = vec4(gDirectionalLight.Color, 1.0f) *
                        gDirectionalLight.AmbientIntensity;

    float DiffuseFactor = dot(normalize(Normal0), -gDirectionalLight.Direction);

    vec4 DiffuseColor;

    if (DiffuseFactor > 0) {
        DiffuseColor = vec4(gDirectionalLight.Color, 1.0f) *
                       gDirectionalLight.DiffuseIntensity *
                       DiffuseFactor;
    }
    else {
        DiffuseColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    vec4 texturesBlend = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

int N = 1;

if(numberOfTextures<=2) {

    for(int i=0;;i++) {
        if(i==numberOfTextures)
            break;
        texturesBlend += texture2D(gSamplers[i], TexCoord0.xy);
    }
    texturesBlend /= numberOfTextures;
}
    FragColor = texturesBlend * (AmbientColor + DiffuseColor);
};
```

Comment: Could you please show you whole Shader source?

Comment: I can even devide some variable by this uniform variable (below for loop), i just can't compare local variable with uniform variable.

Comment: List your linker error, not just the source code that generates it. Lookup `glGetProgramInfoLog (...)`. That information would be very helpful in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: Also, why are you using a for loop like that? The middle statement is a conditional expression; replace it with `i < numberOfTextures`.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman : I think he did that to circumvent the linking error.

Comment: Yes, I did this just for testing. Linking error is "error C5208: Sampler needs to be a uniform (global or parameter to main), need to inline function or resolve conditional expression". The only solution I found is not using array at all. (separate uniform vars instead)

Comment: @user1784182: Have you tried replacing the definition of `MAX_TEXTURES` (currently `const int MAX_TEXTURES = 6;`) with a simple pre-processor `#define MAX_TEXTURES 6`? Also be aware that you should not be using `texture2D (...)` in a GLSL 1.50 shader, use `texture (...)`.